# How can I set rows of images 4 each?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page that pulls images from the Flickr API depending on what the user typed in. As it stands now, the images are retrieved and displayed in a inline-block list of 4 each. However, if an image is wider or narrower than the others it will conflict with the width of the others and either end up on it's own line or will push it onto it's own line.

How can I make sure that at all times, four images are displayed in a row and any new rows also have 4 images. Also, what exactly am I missing with borders on the list items. I add border styles to the li tags and img tags but nothing display?

Thank you for any insight.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
    
    //AJAX
    
        var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        var searchTerm =$('#search').val();
        var userQuery = 
            {
             tags:searchTerm,
            format:"json"
            }; //The data that is actually sent back to Flickr when a request is made for photos
    
        function flickerData (data){
            var photoHTML = '<ul>';
            $.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {
         photoHTML+='<div class="containment"><li class="col-md-3">';
        photoHTML += '<a href="'+photo.link+'">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="'+photo.media.m+'"> </a> </li> </div>';
        
            });
            photoHTML += "</ul>";
            $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
}
    
    $.getJSON(url, userQuery, flickerData);
    
});//end eventsubmit
    
    
    
    
    
    
});
```

```css
}

form{
    margin-top: 5%
}

ul{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    
    

}

li {
    
    margin: 30px 0px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 3%;
    display: inline-block
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flicker.css">
        <title>Testing Access to Flicker API</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="flicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Welcome to the Flicker API search test.</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center">Use the form below to search the open Flicker API based on tag.</h4>
        
        
        <form>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
            <label for="search">What kind of photos are you looking for?</label>
            <input name="search" id="search" class="form-control" type="search" />
            <input type="submit" class='button'/>
            </div>
        </form>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
    
        <ul id="photos"></ul>
    
    
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: You can not set `<li>` as child of `<div>`. it is invalid html and browser will reject it

Comment: If one of the answers (not necessarily mine) have solved your problem please kindly accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaked your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Accessing Flickr API</title>
    <style>
        .row {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Welcome to the Flicker API search test.</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center">Use the form below to search the open Flicker API based on tag.</h4>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="search">What kind of photos are you looking for?</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Flicr Photo">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="photos">
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').submit(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                //AJAX
                var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
                var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
                var userQuery = {
                    tags: searchTerm,
                    format: "json"
                }; //The data that is actually sent back to Flickr when a request is made for photos

                function flickerData(data) {
                    var rowStart = '<div class="row">';
                    var rowEnd = '</div>';
                    var cnt = 0;
                    var photoHTML = '';
                    var dataLength = data.items.length;
                    $.each(data.items, function (i, photo) {
                        if (cnt % 4 == 0) {
                            photoHTML += rowStart;
                        }

                        photoHTML += '<div class="col-md-3">';
                        photoHTML += '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="' + photo.link + '">';
                        photoHTML += '<img class="img-responsive center-block img-rounded img-thumbnail" src="' + photo.media.m + '"> </a> </div>';
                        if ((cnt + 1) % 4 == 0 || (cnt - 1) == dataLength) {
                            photoHTML += rowEnd;
                        }
                        cnt++;

                    });
                    $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
                }
                $.getJSON(url, userQuery, flickerData);
            }); //end eventsubmit
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can also view it in codepen here http://codepen.io/arsho/full/NAabPL/

Answer (score 0):

You can use index "i" and % operator. Make sure you have class row in the container div.

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {
  if ( i % 4 === 0) {
    photoHTML+='<div style="border:1px solid black">';
  }      

  photoHTML+='<li>';
  photoHTML += '<a href="'+photo.link+'">';
  photoHTML += '<img src="'+photo.media.m+'"> </a> </li>';

  if ( i % 4 === 0) {
    photoHTML+='</div>';
  }
});
```

also change #photos to be a div since you cannot have div inside ul

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's still cutting off though. Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: it can be the column/row system class="col-md-3" if you are using bootstrap then you have only 12 cols per row. you can make the container div a row adding class row like this photoHTML+='<div class="row containment">';

Comment: check my updates to the answer, remove classes to test

Comment: This will generate invalid html. `<div>` is invalid parent for  `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

The html you have seems to have a spare ul btw:

MY CODE:

```
ul{
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;
width:1170px;
list-style-type: none;
}

 ul li.col-md-3 {
 padding:0;
 width:auto;
 }

div.containment {    
margin: 30px 0px;
flex:1 1 ((1170px / 4) - (12px * 4)); /* 12px times 4 to allow for borders */
}
```

/* borders */

```
div.containment {    
border:3px dotted Pink;
box-sizing-border-box;
}  

 div.containment li img {    
border:3px double cyan;
box-sizing-border-box;
}
```

YOUR CODE WITH MY ADJUSTMENTS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
    
    //AJAX
    
        var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        var searchTerm =$('#search').val();
        var userQuery = 
            {
             tags:searchTerm,
            format:"json"
            }; //The data that is actually sent back to Flickr when a request is made for photos
    
        function flickerData (data){
            var photoHTML = '<ul>';
            $.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {
         photoHTML+='<div class="containment"><li class="col-md-3">';
        photoHTML += '<a href="'+photo.link+'">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="'+photo.media.m+'"> </a> </li> </div>';
        
            });
            photoHTML += "</ul>";
            $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
}
    
    $.getJSON(url, userQuery, flickerData);
    
});//end eventsubmit
    
    
    
    
    
    
});
```

```css
}

form{
    margin-top: 5%
}

ul{
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;
width:1170px;
list-style-type: none;
}

 ul li.col-md-3 {
 padding:0;
 width:auto;
 }

div.containment {    
margin: 30px 0px;
flex:1 1 ((1170px / 4) - (12px * 4)); /* 12px times 4 to allow for borders */
}  

/* borders */

div.containment {    
border:3px dotted Pink;
box-sizing-border-box;
}  

div.containment li img {    
border:3px double cyan;
box-sizing-border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flicker.css">
        <title>Testing Access to Flicker API</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="flicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Welcome to the Flicker API search test.</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center">Use the form below to search the open Flicker API based on tag.</h4>
        
        
        <form>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
            <label for="search">What kind of photos are you looking for?</label>
            <input name="search" id="search" class="form-control" type="search" />
            <input type="submit" class='button'/>
            </div>
        </form>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
    
        <ul id="photos"></ul>
    
    
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Carol-McKay. It's certianly cleaner than I had before but it's still creating rows with three or sometimes 5. Do you know how I could ensure that the row is always centered/have the same start and end point?

Comment: Please see my edits and the end result. Be sure to use http://autoprefixer.github.io/ and learn flex as it is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, there is no need to write your own styles for making columns, just follow the [Bootstrap Grid System instructions](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Remove your styles and use this markup (there is no need to use `ul/li` also<sup>1</sup>).

```
function flickerData (data) {
    var photoHTML = '<div class="row">';

    $.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {
        photoHTML += '<div class="col-md-3">';
        photoHTML += '<a href="'+photo.link+'">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="'+photo.media.m+'"></a></div>';
    });

    photoHTML += "</div>";

    $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
}
```

---

1 <sub>Your currently HTML markup has some invalid syntax, you can't put `<div>` element directly on the `ul`.</sub>